# Is there anyway to restrict access to Azure blob to a single IP?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to limit access to Azure blobs. I presently can provide a link that is time restricted to 5 minutes using Shared Access Signature. However just wondering if there is any mechanism to require more security such as an IP address?

If not I assume I just have to make the client go via a web role and then check there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Azure Storage Service has a new feature ([shared access signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1)) which allows IP-address whitelisting.

> > A SAS gives you granular control over the type of access you grant to clients who have the SAS, including:
>
> - The interval over which the SAS is valid, including the start time    and the expiry time.
> - The permissions granted by the SAS. For example,    a SAS for a blob might grant read and write permissions to that blob,    but not
>     delete permissions.
> - **An optional IP address or range of IP addresses from which Azure Storage will accept the SAS**. For example, you might specify a range
>     of IP addresses belonging to your organization.
> - The protocol over which Azure Storage will accept the SAS. You can use this optional parameter to restrict access to clients using HTTPS.

Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1)

Comment: Yeah - had noticed that but failed to update my answer. I have accepted your answer - as it is correct.

Comment: Thanks @GraemeMiller

Answer (score 8):

**Update: This is supported now!** Details above on Best Answer. The rest is still of interest so left it in.

N̶o̶ ̶I̶P̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶t̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶s̶u̶p̶p̶o̶r̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶d̶i̶r̶e̶c̶t̶l̶y̶ ̶-̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶r̶s̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶o̶w̶n̶ ̶W̶e̶b̶ ̶R̶o̶l̶e̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶u̶g̶g̶e̶s̶t̶.̶  **But** this is why you should be confident with Shared Access Tokens*:

The only way that SAS blob URL could get mass published and attacked in 5 mins is if there was malicious intent from the recipient. So whatever the method of securing it (e.g. IP restriction) you would be vulnerable because you have given an attacker access. They could just download the data and publish that instead if it was IP restricted.

The shared access token combined with the timeout really prevents brute force attacks guessing the URL or any carelessness in leaving it lying about in an unsecured location over time.

So as long as you trust the person you are sharing with and you transport it to them in a secure manner you are fine.

*in most scenarios

Comment: Yeah. I'd agree. If they have the file downloaded and wanted to be malicious they could just publish it themselves anyway. Seems safe enough

Comment: Azure now supports IP restrictions on SAS tokens - [Apply IP restrictions to an Azure Storage Account](https://ittechlog.wordpress.com/2016/07/13/apply-ip-restrictions-to-an-azure-storage-account/).  It can be done in the portal too

Comment: yeah, thanks for the downvotes you bellends. I wrote this in 2011!

Comment: +1 I find the history of these issues to be of value in filling in the blanks when debugging.  Old info but still very useful in the process if elimination.

Answer (score 1):

There's no additional mechanism for IP filtering. You can direct all traffic through your Web Role and filter traffic there, or use SAS (as you already suggested).

Comment: So SAS for downloads only really allows me to control the time the file is available for from that URL. If someone publishes the URL then anyone can get it?

Comment: SAS is basically a signed URL extension, enabling access to a container or blob for a specific amount of time. Even if someone published the URL, the URL is worthless after the expiration time (you can't modify the SAS unless you have the storage account key). As I don't know your scenario, I don't know the full implications of a brief availability window for a blob or container.

Comment: Cool. It is as I thought. Thanks

Comment: Take note that you can do IP filtering on your SAS token as well - in other words, the token will only be valid for requests from a specific IP or IP range.